# Bootstrap And SASS library are not compatible with each other

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, bootstrap-5

While trying to upgrade Node version in a project.
Which has dependencies on  Bootstrap and SASS

```
Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_containers.scss
Error: From line 30, column 13 of node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_containers.scss:
   ╷
30 │             @extend %responsive-container-#{$breakpoint};
   │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   ╵
You may not @extend selectors across media queries.
   ╷
30 │             @extend %responsive-container-#{$breakpoint};
   │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_containers.scss 30:13  root stylesheet
Details:
    formatted: Error: From line 30, column 13 of node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_containers.scss:
   ╷
30 │             @extend %responsive-container-#{$breakpoint};
   │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   ╵
You may not @extend selectors across media queries.
   ╷
30 │             @extend %responsive-container-#{$breakpoint};
   │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_containers.scss 30:13  root stylesheet
    line: 30
    column: 13
    file: C:\Files\Repos\test2\B###P\S###s\client\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_containers.scss
    status: 1
```

Currently NODE version is V14.21.3

```
"bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
"sass": "1.62.1",
"gulp-sass": "~5.1.0",
```

above all are the latest version of respective libraries.

From above message its visible that gulp-sass detected the error in bootstrap library code.
which means Sass/Gulp-sass is not suporting syntax from bootstrap code.
Is my assumption correct thate their is some compaitable issue with sass and bootstrap.if true? Then why Bootstrap has sass code which is not supported by sass on first place?

Or is their any problem with my approach?

for more info other libraries which I am using in the app.

for the information
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxA8s.png)

list of outdated libs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRUBx.png)